# Inject environment variable value into a json file used by my react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

Here is whta I'm trying to achieve :

I have a react webapp using a configuration file which is a json. 
I need to set some value of this configuration file while building my app.
The value would come from environement variable.

I'm building my application using webpack.

Is there any simple way to achieve this ?